# Azure sharing a folder of files on a File Share

Tags: azure, hyperlink, fileshare

I'm aware you can share individual files via HTTPs URL link + SAS token to access.

Is it possible to share a link to a folder of files this way, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to share a link to a folder of files this way, or is
> there a better way to do this?

With Azure File Service, it is not possible to share a folder using a SAS URL. You can only share a file share or a file using SAS URL.

You may want to look into Azure Data Lake Service. There I believe you can create a SAS URL for a directory.